# Mismatch protocol http and https

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

This issue occurs when the frame requesting access has a protocol of https, the frame being accessed has a protocol of http(toplevel, http://www.example.com/ particularly). how to get around this problem? Thanks for advance!

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, you need to use HTTPS.

Comment: You can't "get around" the problem. You have to properly deal with it and not mix secure and insecure content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to make it protocol agnostic if the frame supports either protocol. That way it'll choose the one being served.

E.g.

```
<img src="//www.placehold.it/250x250" />
```